# Can AutoMapper mappings be composed?

Tags: c#, automapper

The models I'm working with include an entry object which I'd like to map as if its child object were the entire object.

Here is a simplified version of the problem. I'd like an instance of `OurWrappedSource` to map directly to `OurTarget`.

```
class OurTarget
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

class OurSource
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

class OurWrappedSource
{
    public OurSource Source { get; set; }
}

private static void TestUnwrapUsingConfig(MapperConfiguration config)
{
    config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    IMapper mapper = new Mapper(config);

    var wrappedSource = new OurWrappedSource
    {
        Source = new OurSource
        {
            Id = new Guid("123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000"),
            Notes = "Why?",
            Quantity = 27
        }
    };

    var target = mapper.Map<OurTarget>(wrappedSource);

    Assert.Equal(wrappedSource.Source.Id, target.Id);
    Assert.Equal(wrappedSource.Source.Notes, target.Notes);
    Assert.Equal(wrappedSource.Source.Quantity, target.Quantity);
}
```

The following configuration works, but is unwieldy for more than a couple of members:

```
// Works, but isn't *auto* enough
TestUnwrapUsingConfig(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<OurWrappedSource, OurTarget>()
        .ForMember(src => src.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(wrappedSource => wrappedSource.Source.Id))
        .ForMember(src => src.Notes, opts => opts.MapFrom(wrappedSource => wrappedSource.Source.Notes))
        .ForMember(src => src.Quantity, opts => opts.MapFrom(wrappedSource => wrappedSource.Source.Quantity));
}));
```

What I'd like to be able to do is define two intermediate mappings an then compose them:

1. Map `OurWrappedSource` directly to `OurSource`
2. Map `OurSource` directly to `OurTarget`
3. Map `OurWrappedSource` to `OurTarget` by composing mapping 1 with mapping 2

After some hammering, I have this configuration:

```
// Works, but #3 probably isn't ProjectTo-friendly
TestUnwrapUsingConfig(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    // 1
    cfg.CreateMap<OurWrappedSource, OurSource>()
        .ConvertUsing(wrappedSource => wrappedSource.Source);

    // 2
    cfg.CreateMap<OurSource, OurTarget>();

    // 3
    cfg.CreateMap<OurWrappedSource, OurTarget>()
        .ConstructUsing((wrappedSource, ctx) =>
            ctx.Mapper.Map<OurTarget>(ctx.Mapper.Map<OurSource>(wrappedSource))
            )
        .ForAllOtherMembers(opts => opts.Ignore());
}));
```

This works exactly as specified, but mapping 3 seems perhaps a little more explicit and/or kludgey than it should. It involves code in a `Func` (rather than an expression), which makes me think it probably won't optimize well when used with `ProjectTo()`. Is there a way to rewrite mapping 3 to address these issues?

Comment: In step 3, you need ConvertUsing and then you can remove ForAllOtherMembers.

Comment: May be you need [IncludeMembers](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/d018ae4e538c3023bef1666d40c281ca1f0fe7b5/docs/Flattening.md#includemembers). Not sure if it is released yet though.

Comment: IncludeMembers is in the [MyGet](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/The-MyGet-build.html) build.